# remove element from array where element equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

for example i have this array

```
    var array1 = [{ uid=24433357, first_name="fname", last_name="lname", ...},
{ uid=4821888, first_name="fname", last_name="lname", ...},
{ uid=677614, first_name="fname", last_name="lname", ...},
{ uid=4789723, first_name="fname", last_name="lname", ...},
{ uid=444464, first_name="fname", last_name="lname", ...},
{ uid=767687867, first_name="fname", last_name="lname", ...}]
```

i want to remove element from array1 where uid = x

i have no idea how?

for normal arrays i know this method

```
array1.splice(index, count)
```

Comment: Loop through all elements in array1. If uid of array1[i] = x add it to array2. Once your loop's finished array1 = array2.

Comment: Your array will have many syntax errors in it btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix your objects first, the syntax is all wrong. See below and then use the Array#filter function to filter out the unwanted object by its `uid`

```
var array1 = [{ uid:24433357, first_name:"fname", last_name:"lname"},
    { uid:4821888, first_name:"fname", last_name:"lname"},
    { uid:677614, first_name:"fname", last_name:"lname"},
    { uid:4789723, first_name:"fname", last_name:"lname"},
    { uid:444464, first_name:"fname", last_name:"lname"},
    { uid:767687867, first_name:"fname", last_name:"lname"}];
```

**ES5** not suitable for old browsers

```
array1 = array1.filter(function(o){
    return o.uid !== 24433357
});
```

**Classic Way** compatible with old browsers

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

    if (array1[i].uid === 24433357) {
        array1.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: I know that the syntax is incorrect, the syntax is not important in this case, the main thing here is solution ))) thanks)))

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var i = array1.length-1; i--;){
    if (array1.uid[i] === "x") array1.splice(i, 1);
}
```